# How to list systemd unit files with descriptions

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

The command

```
systemctl list-units
```

only displays instances of units, such that are currently loaded into the memory.
The command

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

on the other hand lists all unit configuration files found in the search paths.
Unfortunately, the latter does not include descriptions.

Is there a handy command with which one could list all unit files with their descriptions?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
systemctl list-units --all
```

upd:

from systemctl man page

> **list-unit-files** [PATTERN...]
> List unit files installed on the system, in combination with their enablement state .....

> Unlike **list-units** this command will list template units in addition to explicitly instantiated units.

template units have @ in the name

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type service | grep -i "@"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be a solution. 'Systemctl list-unit-files' lists units that aren't listed in 'systemctl list-units --all'